# Fetching n bytes from memory

Tags: c

Suppose I have a pointer to image data which has 3 channels (RGB), 8 bits per channel and I want to display the value of a pixel like #000000, which is a 24 bit number. The data is stored like RGB RGB RGB ... so I really need to read the first three bytes.

```
typedef unsigned char uchar;
uchar* data = get_image_data_somehow();
```

Maybe it's easier than I think, but if I had four bytes, I could do something like

```
uint32 value = *((uint32*) data);
printf("Value is %x", value);
```

How is that to be done? In principle I need the 32 bit one, and fill the leading 8 bits with zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
memcpy( &value, data, 3 );
value &= 0x00FFFFFF;
```

(assuming you're on a Little-Endian machine)

Comment: What's about LE? There is a strict byte ordering, as author mentioned.

Comment: So memcpy would then align the three bytes on the right hand side if source (three bytes) and target (4 bytes) have different sizes?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs yeah, nothing.

@wal-o-mat Right; the contents of other bytes in target is unchanged (so if it is unknown, it's safer to clear it). Moreover, `memcpy` won't read more memory than necessary, whereas copying uint32 will make a 4-byte read. There's nothing to worry about in your case, though.

Answer (score 4):

You can bit-shift right by 8 bits to achive this.

```
uint32_t value = *((uint32_t*) data) >> 8;
printf("Value is %0X", value);
```

Example where `data` is two pixels of value `#1177ff`:

```
data       = 11 77 ff 11 77 ff
value      = 11 77 ff 11
value >> 8 = 00 11 77 ff
```

Comment: `%0X` would look better. +1'd.

Comment: @AdamZalcman: Just an example and to clarify which size the data type has. GLib for example provides the corresponding typedefs like guint32, just using plain "int" may differ from machine to machine I think.

Comment: @AdamZalcman - There is in OP's code. I'm assuming he's got it typedef'ed somewhere. If you don't like `uint32`, feel free to substitute `uint32_t` or `unsigned int`, though any 32-bit unsigned integer type you happen to have available will do the job.

Comment: @AdamZalcman - Ah yes, forgot that one. I was thinking `int` was fixed due to the whole `int`/`long int`/`long long` deal. I'll update the original code to use `uint32_t`.

Comment: Well, the approach seems reasonable, but somehow ... fetching the first byte (unsigned char) returns me "0x2A", which is what I expected. But fetching the first four bytes with what you suggested (without the shifting) returns me "0x2727262A" which is the mirrored what I expect, the first 0x27 is the red value of the second pixel. Does this have to do then with little endian and so on? After the shifting then the 0x27 is returned (and not the 0x2A2627 as expected)

Comment: It should only be fetching the data as you've specified it. Endianness only matters when you explicitly do integer operations rather than data copies. Are you sure it's not in BGR format? (this is quite common)

Comment: My machine seems to be little endian, so the example is not working. I think I can explain it: `unsigned char ham[4] = {0x2a, 0x26, 0x27, 0x27};` converted to an unsigned integer with `unsigned int spam = *((unsigned int*) ham);` returns (printed) `0x2727262A`. And this is exaclty the problen I run into. The good news is, that it's easy to work around this once you know the problem ;)

Comment: And so, masking with 00FFFFFF does the trick, but I need to keep in mind that it reverses the channel order and RGB gets BGR. In memory it was 'R1 G1 B1 R2 G2 B2 ...', reading the first four bytes into an unsigned integer results in 'R2 B1G1 R1' (little endian) , I masked the first R (which is the red value of the _next_ pixel) which leaves me 'B1 G1 R1' and I have the desired result, at least nearly.

Comment: Yeah. It's odd that the endianness matters though.

Comment: It's just an interpretation issue. Assuming you have 16 bits per channel, it gets really important to clarify that (because you compose a number of two bytes and don't just have three independent numbers like I do).

Answer (score 0):

you could use a **[union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28computer_science%29)**  to extract the data, or departmentalize it.

It will look something like this:

```
union myRGB {
    unsigned int data;
    struct RGB
    {
       unsigned char a, b, g, r;
    }
}

myRGB value = *((uint32*) data);

printf("R Value is %x", value.RGB.a);
```

**[RGB parsing example](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/cplusplus/example_of_using_union_in_cplusplus.xml)**

Comment: I would set +1 here as well, but I think your code is not well written and has an error.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs might have an error, just drafted it for the concept, can you point the error ?

Comment: Well, I you have fixed few things. I was thinking about endianness here, it's not really error though, but it might not work on some architectures. Check the comments under Polynomial's answer.